# need the way to put Date in Parse.com without Time and the opposite

Tags: android, date, time, parse-platform

Can't figured how to put just Date or just Time to Parse.com.
Even after SimpleDateFormat the Date objects transferring with full default missing data.

Code samples:

```
DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
DateFormat timeFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm");
try {
    date = dateFormat.parse(mDate.getText().toString());
    time = timeFormat.parse(mTime.getText().toString());
} catch (java.text.ParseException e) {

...

meeting.put(ParseConstants.KEY_DATE, date);
meeting.put(ParseConstants.KEY_TIME, time);
```

but on Parse.com I received 2 DATE Objects with full date parameters: date and time at both of them.

Any idea what I need to do?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: I think that what I want is not possible to do due to Date object is the time from 1970 counted in milliseconds (fix me if I wrong). So I can't disassemble time from a date in the object but only in view of it, for example, printing in textView. Still would be glad for different ways to deal it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I finally did.

I used Calender class and filled each item(year, month, day, hour, minute) while using date and time pickers. And used Calendar.getTime method to transform it to Date class that Parse.com understand.

```
Calendar mDateTime = Calendar.getInstance();
...
mDateTime.set(Calendar.YEAR, selectedYear);
mDateTime.set(Calendar.MONTH, selectedMonth);
mDateTime.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, selectedDay);
...
meeting.put(ParseConstants.KEY_DATETIME, mDateTime.getTime());
```

So I still have to inputs for date and time and working parse date class.